# How can I extract the exact template from this PDF page to a WORD file.I want the same template.I read that I can do it using the XML files in the PDF

Tags: pdf, docx

How can I extract the exact template from this PDF page to a WORD file. I want the same template. I read that I can do it using the XML files in the PDF.Is there better program  than Microsoft WORD to make such template or extract it from an pdf file.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *tample* ? That's not a real word in the English language ...

Comment: sorry for that. I edited it and thanks for the note

Comment: What do you mean by "template"? Something like "two column text with header with colored backgrounds"?

Comment: mkl-ya exactly and the hole shape of the page(see the page number in corner and the chapter)

Comment: thanks KJ.I tried the site but couldn't find the template. I guess the template was designed for this book only. I just want to translate the page(and other pages from the same book) so the new "translated pages"should have the same shape as of the origin pages. And for the LaTex Is it better than Word and can I make the same template using it?